# Why cv2.imread can't read all my folder from my path folder?

Tags: python, opencv

I have two types of machine learning model. One of my model works well when I want to read and display how many folder there are in my path. In my second model, I tried to use the same code to read the folder but it gives me error.

The output supposed to be like this:

```
There are 40 images in category 1
There are 40 images in category 2
```

This is the code that I run to produce the output above (This is from my first ml model):

```
for category in category_im_listing: # Read files one by one
    im_listing = os.listdir(dataset_path + "/" + category)
    num_im = size(im_listing)
    print("There are " + str(num_im) + " images in category " + str(count + 1))
    for file in im_listing:
        img = Image.open(dataset_path + "/" + category + "/" + file) # open file
        img = img.resize((150,150))
        gray = img.convert('L') # convert the image to single channel 
        # calculate HOG
        fd = hog(gray, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, block_norm='L2', feature_vector=True)
        data.append(fd)
        labels.append(count)
    count = count + 1
```

However, when I try to use the same code for my second model, it shows output like this:

```
There are 50 images in category 1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
1
1
1
1
2
```

Here the code that I run on my second model which cause me to get an error like above, in my first code I use Image.open but here I changed it to cv2.imread because when I tried to use to exact same code like in the first model, it gives me error. But if I change to cv2 it can read but only one category folder:

```
for category in category_im_listing: #reading files one by one
    im_listing = os.listdir(image_path + "/" + category)
    num_im = size(im_listing)
    print("There are " + str(num_im) + " images in category " + str(count + 1))
    for file in im_listing:
        img=cv2.imread(image_path + "/" + category + "/" + file) # I changed Image.open to cv2.imread
        # calculate PHOG
        p = phog(img, bin, angle, L, roi)#I changed this part
        data.append(p)
        labels.append(count)
    count = count + 1
```

How can I fix my code to produce the produce output like I had in my first model?

Comment: What do you mean by "different model"? Are you applying the same code over different input (directory structure) ?

Comment: I make svm with hog feature descriptor model, and svm with phog feature descriptor model. I use the same svm model, and just changed a line for the feature descriptor from hog to phog. I also use the same path directory for both model, just want to see which model can produce better accuracy.